# Cannot see Profile photo of user after signing in

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, react-hooks

I have made a MERN Stack Authentication Web application.
Up until yesterday when a user logs in with his google account, he could see the profile photo too but now when I resumed my work today, I am not able to see the profile photo.

Here is the code for the profile code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  getDownloadURL,
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytesResumable,
} from "firebase/storage";
import { app } from "../firebase";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  updateUserStart,
  updateUserSuccess,
  updateUserFailure,
  deleteUserStart,
  deleteUserSuccess,
  deleteUserFailure,
  signOut,
} from "../redux/user/userSlice";

export default function Profile() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fileRef = useRef(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(undefined);
  const [imagePercentage, setImagePercentage] = useState(0);
  console.log(imagePercentage);
  const [imageError, setImageError] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [updateSuccess, setUpdateSuccess] = useState(false);

  const { currentUser, loading, error } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      handleFileUpload(image);
    }
  }, [image]);
  const handleFileUpload = async (image) => {
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + image.name;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, fileName);
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        setImagePercentage(Math.round(progress));
      },
      (error) => {
        setImageError(true);
        console.error(error);
      },
      () => {
        getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
          .then((downloadURL) => {
            setFormData({ ...formData, profilePicture: downloadURL });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setImageError(true);
            console.error("Error getting download URL:", error);
          });
      }
    );
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      dispatch(updateUserStart());
      const res = await fetch(`/api/user/update/${currentUser._id}`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      if (data.success === false) {
        dispatch(updateUserFailure(data));
        return;
      }
      dispatch(updateUserSuccess(data));

      setUpdateSuccess(true);
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(updateUserFailure(error));
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteAccount = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(deleteUserStart());
      const res = await fetch(`/api/user/delete/${currentUser._id}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      if (data.success === false) {
        dispatch(deleteUserFailure(data));
        return;
      }
      dispatch(deleteUserSuccess(data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(deleteUserFailure(error));
    }
  };

  const handleSignOut = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch("/api/auth/signout");
      dispatch(signOut());
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error signing out: ", error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="p-3 max-w-lg mx-auto">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold text-center my-7">Profile</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="flex flex-col gap-4">
        <input
          type="file"
          ref={fileRef}
          hidden
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
        ></input>
        <img
          src={formData.profilePicture || currentUser.profilePicture}
          alt="profile"
          className="h-24 w-24 self-center cursor-pointer rounded-full mb-5 mt-2"
          onClick={() => fileRef.current.click()}
        ></img>
        <p className="text-sm self-center">
          {imageError ? (
            <span className="text-red-700">
              Error Uploading the Image(File Size must be less than 5MB)
            </span>
          ) : imagePercentage > 0 && imagePercentage < 100 ? (
            <span className="text-blue-700">
              {" "}
              {`Uploading: ${imagePercentage} %`}
            </span>
          ) : imagePercentage === 100 ? (
            <span className="text-green-700">Image uploaded successfully</span>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </p>
        <input
          defaultValue={currentUser.username}
          type="text"
          id="username"
          placeholder="Username"
          className="bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3 "
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></input>
        <input
          defaultValue={currentUser.email}
          type="email"
          id="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          className="bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3 "
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></input>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          className="bg-slate-100 rounded-lg p-3 "
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></input>
        <button className="bg-slate-700 text-white p-3 rounded-lg uppercase hover:opacity-95 disabled:opacity-80">
          {loading ? "loading..." : "Update"}
        </button>
      </form>
      <div className="flex justify-between mt-5">
        <button>
          <span onClick={handleDeleteAccount} className="text-red-600">
            Delete Account
          </span>
        </button>
        <button>
          <span onClick={handleSignOut} className="text-red-600">
            Sign Out
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <p className="text-red-700 mt-5">{error && "Something went wrong"}</p>
      <p className="text-green-700 mt-5">
        {updateSuccess && "User Updated Successfully"}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the Auth Controller:

```
import User from "../models/user.model.js";
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";
import { errorHandler } from "../utils/error.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, 10);
  const newUser = new User({ username, email, password: hashedPassword });
  try {
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: "User Created Succesfully!" });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

export const signin = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const validUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!validUser) return next(errorHandler(404, "User not found"));
    const validPassword = bcryptjs.compareSync(password, validUser.password);
    if (!validPassword) return next(errorHandler(401, "Wrong Credentials!!"));
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: validUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const { password: hashedPassword, ...rest } = validUser._doc;
    const expireyDate = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000); // 1 Hour
    res
      .cookie("access_token", token, { httpOnly: true, expires: expireyDate })
      .status(200)
      .json(rest);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

export const google = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      const { password: hasedPassword, ...rest } = user._doc;
      const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 360000000);
      res
        .cookie("access_token", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          expires: expiryDate,
        })
        .status(200)
        .json(rest);
    } else {
      const generatedPassword = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
      +Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
      const hasedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(generatedPassword, 10);
      const newUser = new User({
        username:
          req.body.name.split(" ").join("").toLowerCase() +
          Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8),
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hasedPassword,
        profilePicture: req.body.photo,
      });
      await newUser.save();
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: newUser._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      const { password: hashedPassword2, ...rest } = newUser._doc;
      const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 360000000);
      res
        .cookie("access_token", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          expires: expiryDate,
        })
        .status(200)
        .json(rest);
    }
  } catch (error) {}
};

export const signout = (req, res) => {
  res
    .clearCookie("access_token")
    .status(200)
    .json("Signed Out Successfully!! ");
};
```

This is the Header Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
export default function Header() {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-200">
      <div
        className=" flex justify-between items-center
      max-w-6xl mx-auto p-3"
      >
        <Link to={"/home"}>
          <h1 className="font-bold">Auth App</h1>
        </Link>
        <ul className="flex gap-4">
          <Link to={"/home"}>
            <li>Home</li>
          </Link>
          <Link to={"/about"}>
            <li>About</li>
          </Link>
          <Link to={"/profile"}>
            {currentUser ? (
              <img
                src={currentUser.profilePicture}
                alt="profile"
                className="h-7 w-7 rounded-full object-cover"
              />
            ) : (
              <li>Sign in</li>
            )}
          </Link>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Last time I faced this problem, What I did was that I increased the expiry date of the cookie,
and I will be honest, it was just a trial and error kind of a hunch and it worked perfectly at that time.
But after I closed the terminal and the website and tried it again the problem presented itself again.

Now I cannot see the profile photo on the header as well. and the profile page where I had also give user the ability to change the photo using firebase.

Now when the user changes the photo and uploads it. It is visible on the page but not on the header.

Kindly help